# Change made to $scope variable through event captured by $rootScope doesn't update in view

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, ionic-framework

I have a somewhat old ionic App (ionic v 1.3.x). Based on certain asynchronous changes detected in another part of the App it emits $rootScope level events. I catch that event in a Controller to update the view when that event is caught. Something along the lines below.

```
// In a different part of the App an asynchronous event is caught
$rootScope.$emit("some:change:event", grpKey); // from asynchronous event

// In Controller
$rootScope.$on("some:change:event", function(event, param){
   reComputeValues(param);
}

function reComputeValues(param){
  $scope.someVariable = updated value;
  //$scope.$apply();
}

function reComputeValues_withApply(param){
   $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.someVariable = updated value;
   });
}
```

Even though the $scope.someVariable is being updated (I can see it when stepping through it in the debugger), the change is not reflected in the view when I am on the view. If I move away from that view and come back to the view, the page reloads and the change is there.

After digging around it first seemed the $apply call should do the trick. I did that two different ways as above (just calling $scope.$apply or encapsulating the variable update within the $apply call). While this does update the view it gives a few errors which seem to be related to some scope issue. I realized it could be because when the event is captured and the function is called it is in the context of $rootScope and the variable is updated at $scope level which is why it is not automatically updating the view and giving errors when forcing the $apply call. But $scope is also a child of $rootScope so I don't fully understand the $rootScope and $scope interaction here and why the view is not updating.

Appreciate any pointers on how best to address this issue.

Thanks,
Sanjay.

Comment: can you provide us with some html? In the script are a few mistakes but i think that because it just to show us the idea but there is missing a ")" for the $on. And maybe "updated value" too param. Just to be sure a working plunk of you problem would be perfect, because it should work like that without the $apply.

Comment: @Carsten - Sorry for the delay. Yes the missing bracket is just in the example above - not in code. Relevant HTML is below

`            <span style="font-size: 11px;">
                Need ride: {{gt_countH.needRideCount}}   &nbsp;&nbsp; Have Ride: {{gt_countH.haveRideCount}} &nbsp;&nbsp; Open Spots: {{gt_countH.availablePoolCapacity}}
            </span>
`
In Controller the $scope variable is set as below
`$scope.gt_countH = <Function call that returns the hash with the values>`

Thank you for your thoughts

Comment: Sorry the code formatting doesn't seem to have come out right in the comment above

Comment: It could be because you said $scope.gt_countH is a function. You could try to send a normal parameter and check if that parameter will be changed in your view

Comment: Thanks @MrWook. $scope.gt_countH is a Hash with the values of needRideCount, haveRideCount, availablePoolCapacity set when reComputeValues function is called. So the expectation is that when those Hash values change that should be reflected in the view.

The thing I am not clear about is that the async event executes in the context of $rootScope and the variables are set in the $scope. Is there some dynamics there and why is $scope.$apply or $rootScope.$apply giving the error noted in the answer below.

Comment: So it is not a function? I'm kind of confused. I would love to help you out so please provide me with an example on plnkr.co or another site. If you create the hash value by yourself you need to trigger it again after you changed a value of it. The error occures because you are already inside a digest cycle and $apply will trigger a new one. You could wrap it around a $timeout. But that would be bad practice

Answer (score 0):

Can u please try the following changed code and let me know.

```
$rootScope.$emit("some:change:event", grpKey); // from asynchronous event

// In Controller
$rootScope.$on("some:change:event", function(event, param){
    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
        reComputeValues(param); 
    });
}

function reComputeValues(param){
    $scope.someVariable = updated value;
    //$scope.$apply();
}

function reComputeValues_withApply(param){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.someVariable = updated value;
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your thoughts. I tried that and get similar error at $rootScope level. Error snippet below.

`angular.js:13920 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at angular.js:38
    at n (angular.js:18042)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:17780)`